# Webpack build all js files in project to multiple output files

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to change my webpack config file to handle all js and jsx files in project to a multiple output files (output file name should be the entry file name). 
I didnt find any simple solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple entry files, and keep the name in the output files.

```
entry: {
    src: './src/app.js',
    foo: './src/foo.js',
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].js',
},
```

From the documentation:

```
If an object is passed, each key is the name of a chunk, and the value 
describes the entrypoint for the chunk.
```

You can also pass a function as the entry to do more complicated things.

**EDIT:**
For example, this script will glob all js files in the src directory and create an entry point for each.

```
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = () => {

    return {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: () => {
            return glob.sync('./src/*.js').reduce((pre, cur) => {
                pre[cur.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').split('.')[0]] = cur;
                return pre;
            }, {});
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: '[name].js',
        },
    };
};
```

You can probably clean up the regex a bit

Comment: Yes but my goal is: when a developer adds new jsx file to project he doesn't need to change the config file. So i cant explicitly write the files path...

Comment: you have to be a bit more specific for me to help you. What doesn't work, do you get any errors?

Comment: The output file name is 0... And there aren't multiple output files. I will point my goal i expected that sub folders in dist will be my sub folders names and the jsx files will be in the those sub folders. Any idea why the output is name is 0?Thnks!

Comment: Can you try this one and see if it works. https://github.com/lukas-reineke/webpack-glob-example